# C program crashes when accessing next element in array of struct

Tags: c, pointers, crash

```
void struct_tokens(struct Words **w_count, int size)
{
    *w_count = (struct Words*)calloc(size, sizeof(struct Words)); 
    char *temp;
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    printf("Value 1: %s\n", (*w_count[0]).word);
    printf("Value 2: %s\n", (*w_count[1]).word);
}
```

My struct looks like this:

```
struct Words
{
    char word[20];
    unsigned int count;
};
```

It crashes as soon as I access the next element in the array, so w_count[0] is accessed but it cannot access w_count[1] without crashing. So the Value 1 prints to console but Value 2 does not, why is this?

Comment: How is `struct_tokens()` called, and how are the variables passed in set.

Comment: Show us a full program that's as simple as possible that still has this issue.

Comment: The answer holds - earlier within given code the way you accessed lead to undefined behavior. But Then correcting that if you still get error then there is something you didn;t show

Comment: The call to `calloc()` looks more like a call to `malloc()` with a typo in its name.

Comment: @alk changed the typo

Comment: There is no need to cast the result of `calloc()` in C. Does the real code `#include` `<stdlib.h>`?

Comment: @coderredoc I rechecked my code and it appears I didn't change fully one of your lines, cheers for that mate it seems to work now :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `calloc` call is wrong - it would be

```
*w_count = calloc(size, sizeof(struct Words));
```

Accessing the instance of the structure would be

```
printf("Value 1: %s\n", (*w_count)[0].word);
```

`[]` has higher [precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) than `*`. In earlier case you were having undefined behavior (which lead to the crash).

Also note that the memory allocated will be initialized with `0`. As a result the char arrays will contain nothing other than `\0` - it won't print anything when used in `printf`.

Few points:

- `void*` to `struct Words *` conversion is done implicitly - you don't need to cast it.
- Check the return value of `calloc` in case it returns `NULL` you should handle it appropriately.
- Free the dynamically allocated memory when you are done working with it. (using `free()` ).
- Code wise the correct code for `calloc` would be like this:-

  ```
  *w_count = calloc(size, sizeof(struct Words));
  if( *w_count == NULL ){
     perror("calloc");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  ```